# Python (Tkinter) created menu wont show up

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm trying to make a top level file menu for a Tkinter and it is not showing up. I dont think I need to pack() it since it is in the master

```
from Tkinter import *

class MazeApp(object):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        master.minsize(300, 300)

        self.makeMenu(master)

    def makeMenu(self, master):
        menubar = Menu(master)

        filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.test)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.test)
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.test)

        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)


    def onExit(self):
        master.destroy()

    def test(self):
        pass

def main():

    root = Tk()
    app = MazeApp(root)
    root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

All that shows up is the 300*300 windows but the menu is the default one. Any ideas on where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to inform the root widget that you're assigning it a menubar.  Include this line after you've created the menubar:

```
master.config(menu=menubar)
```